# Javascript custom object needs to listen to another custom objects event

Tags: javascript, events

I'm trying to have a custom object listen to an event of another custom object. How can I do this? I've made a small example of a patient and a nurse. When patient screams the nurse needs to pick up the phone and call 911.

```
function Patient(name) {
    this.Name = name;

    this.Scream = function (terribleSound) {
        alert(terribleSound);
        if (typeof this.OnScream === "function") {
            setTimeout(this.OnScream(this), 1);
        }
    }
}

function Nurse(name, patient) {
    this.Name = name;
    this.Patient = patient;

    this.Patient.OnScream = function (sender) {
        alert(sender.Name + ' screamed');
    }
}

var patient = new Patient('John');
var nurse = new Nurse('Jane', patient);
patient.Scream('AAAAAAAHHHHHHHHhhhhhh!');
```

This works but now I want to have the name of the nurse inside the alert like:

```
alert(this.Name + ' heard ' + sender.Name + ' scream.');
```

But *this* is the same as the *sender* and it outputs: "John heard John scream.". That's quite fine but I wanted Jane to hear John scream. How can I solve this JavaScript puzzle?

Best regards,
Rémy Samulski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need a timeout in `Scream` function. But if you do, look at this:

```
this.Scream = function (terribleSound) {
    alert(terribleSound);
    if (typeof this.OnScream === "function") {
        setTimeout(function(){this.OnScream(this)}.bind(this), 1);
    }
}
```

If you don't need timeout:

```
this.Scream = function (terribleSound) {
    alert(terribleSound);
    if (typeof this.OnScream === "function") {
        this.OnScream(this);
    }
}
```

**UPD**

Now I have found the solution. You need to pass context of `Nurse` to patient's `OnScream`.

Try this one:

```
function Nurse(name, patient) {
    this.Name = name;
    this.Patient = patient;

    this.Patient.OnScream = function (sender) {
        alert(this.Name + ' heard ' + sender.Name + ' scream.');
    }.bind(this);
}
```

or with closure:

```
function Nurse(name, patient) {
    var self = this;
    this.Name = name;
    this.Patient = patient;

    this.Patient.OnScream = function (sender) {
        alert(self.Name + ' heard ' + sender.Name + ' scream.');
    };
}
```

Comment: Thx for your suggestions. Have tried both examples but still only John hears himself scream and Jane still doesn't hear John scream. I used the timeout to wait until the this.Scream function ended before Jane's onScream reaction to it. When I don't use the timeout the "event" is already triggered before ending the actual this.Scream.

Comment: Thank you very much, both solutions work. I'll have a look what this _bind()_ function does. THX!